# Translating C code to OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am trying to translate a smaller program written in C into openCL. I am supposed to transfer some input data to the GPU and then perform ALL calculations on the device using successive kernel calls.

However, I am facing difficulties with parts of the code that are not suitable for parallelization since I must avoid transferring data back and forth between CPU and GPU because of the amount of data used.

Is there a way to execute some kernels without the parallel processing so I can replace these parts of code with them? Is this achieved by setting global work size to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute code serially on OpenCL devices. To do this, write your kernel code the same as you would in C and then execute it with the [clEnqueueTask()](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueTask.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage two **devices** :

- the **GPU** for highly parallelized code
- the **CPU** for sequential code

This is a bit complex as you must manage one **command-queue** by device to schedule each kernel on the appropriate device.

If the devices are part of the same **platform** (typically AMD) you can use the same **context**, otherwise you will have to create one more context for the CPU.

Moreover, if you want to have a more fine-grained CPU **task-parallelization** you could use **device-fission** if your CPU supports it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to openCL so forgive me if this is a stupid question but if I have two contexts ( Intel CPU and nVidia GPU ) doesn't that mean that I still have to send data back and forth?

Comment: You could use pinned-memory with memory-mappings : CPU will have direct access to the memory, and GPU may copy the necessary parts to its global memory. If you have a lot of data movements compared to processing you may have to adapt your algorithm. In the ideal case you'll be able to run CPU  and GPU concurrently.